# What does WaitForAck do in SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I am considering using SignalR for server-to-client real time communication.  However, I need to guarantee delivery, so I need some form of ACK in the process.

I have seen answers here with suggestions for how to do this, but I also see that the Microsoft documentation for SignalR includes a Message.WaitForAck bool property.  This makes me hopeful that perhaps Microsoft baked something in to do this--but I can find no postings at all of folks using this, nor any posts explaining what it does.

Is it just an inert flag?  That is, are we still on the hook to roll our own ACK system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WaitForAck is an internal thing. SignalR is build around a MessageBus where WaitForAck is used for some operations that should block until completed (or timed out). An example of such operation would be adding connection to a group. 
If you want a guarantee delivery you need to implement it on your own on top of SignalR.